# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'df'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a current project, I am planning to clean a Pandas DataFrame off its Null values. For this purpose, I want to use `Pandas.DataFrame.fillna`, which is apparently a solid soliton for data cleanups.

When running the below code, I am however receiving the following error `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'df'`. I tried several options to rewrite the line `df = pd.df().fillna`, none of which changed the outcome.

Is there any smart tweak to get this running?

```
import string
import json
import pandas as pd

# Loading and normalising the input file
file = open("sp500.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = pd.df().fillna
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load the file to the pandas - in your code the `data` variable is a `DataFrame` instance. However, you made a typo.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = df.fillna()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This result is yielding `ValueError: Must specify a fill 'value' or 'method'.`. The approach `df = pd.DataFrame().fillna` seems to work however

Comment: @M.S. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html here are the docs. You need to set a few variables. If that works out please upvote my answer and accept it :) `df = pd.DataFrame().fillna(value = ' DataFrame'`should work out

Comment: @M.S. as it working, can you please accept my answer and upvote me? :))